# Building deep learning from config file using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, caffe

I would like to ask whether there is any method at hand to build deep learning models from config file using Tensorflow, just like that in caffe. Thank you very much.

Comment: Literally the first result in a Google search: [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow).

Comment: Thank you very much, How can I give you the "Correct" mark?

Comment: It was just a comment because I haven't tried the tool and I was not sure if it would fulfil your requirements, but I have added it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project [caffe-tensorflow](https://github.com/ethereon/caffe-tensorflow) allows you to convert Caffe models to TensorFlow.